# Firefox keeps reopening tabs I've closed

Tags: firefox

When I try to open a new window, Firefox tries to restore an old session and load like 20-something pages - all of which I have closed many times before. I've closed them and then quit Firefox. It doesn't matter, it insists on reopening them.

How can I purge these pages once and for all? I don't care about restoring this session - just want to be able to use my browser normally again.

Within `profilename.default` there is a subfolder named `sessionstore-backups`, but deleting that folder or even deleting specific recovery files within it do not remedy the problem because Firefox just repopulates the session data from... somewhere?!

Firefox 68.0.1 macOS 10.12.6

Comment: Have you tried to delete the Firefox profile?

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, and that's where things get really stupid. Firefox refuses to start without the profile.

Comment: Use the profile manager to delete the current user profile then create a new one.

Comment: Except that I don't actually want to lose all of my profile data. Can someone tell me where the session data is stored, so I can remove just that?

Comment: The session data is stored within the Firefox profile directory.

Comment: I didn't mean for my last comment to **sound condescending**, I simply indicated, where the session data was stored.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm sorry, I was being rude. I'm having one of those days where absolutely nothing works the way it's supposed to. Not your fault.